# Getting error for my comment module using socket and angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using socket and angular.js for comment section in my node.js express project and getting following error.

```
 (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.
 11 clear_comments listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
 at Namespace.addListener (events.js:252:17)
 at Server.(anonymous function) [as on] (/home/comeoutloud/public_html/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:369:16)
 at Namespace.<anonymous> (/home/comeoutloud/public_html/controllers/usermains.js:1761:10)
 at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Namespace.emit (/home/comeoutloud/public_html/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:206:10)
at /home/comeoutloud/public_html/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:174:14
at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
```